# unable to install virtualbox

Tags: package-management, virtualbox, dependencies

```
root@-Lenovo-ideapad-320-15IKB:/home/snowden/Downloads# apt install virtualbox
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 virtualbox : Depends: virtualbox-dkms (>= 6.1.6-dfsg-1) but it is not going to be installed or
                       virtualbox-source (>= 6.1.6-dfsg-1) but it is not going to be installed or
                       virtualbox-modules
              Depends: libgsoap-2.8.91 but it is not going to be installed
              Conflicts: virtualbox-6.1 but 6.1.40-154048~Ubuntu~jammy is to be installed
              Recommends: virtualbox-qt (= 6.1.6-dfsg-1) but it is not going to be installed
 virtualbox-6.1 : Depends: libc6 (>= 2.34) but 2.31-0ubuntu9.7 is to be installed
                  Depends: libqt5core5a (>= 5.15.1) but 5.12.8+dfsg-0ubuntu2.1 is to be installed
                  Depends: libqt5gui5 (>= 5.14.1) but 5.12.8+dfsg-0ubuntu2.1 is to be installed or
                           libqt5gui5-gles (>= 5.14.1) but it is not going to be installed
                  Depends: libqt5widgets5 (>= 5.15.1) but 5.12.8+dfsg-0ubuntu2.1 is to be installed
                  Depends: libssl3 (>= 3.0.0~~alpha1) but it is not installable
                  Depends: libstdc++6 (>= 11) but 10.3.0-1ubuntu1~20.04 is to be installed
                  Depends: libvpx7 (>= 1.10.0) but it is not installable
                  Conflicts: virtualbox
                  Recommends: libsdl-ttf2.0-0 but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

Comment: Welcome to AU. There’s not really a question here - you’ve just pasted some terminal output. If you could edit your question to try to put some information in - about your system, what you’re trying to do, what you’ve tried etc.  - then you’re likely to get help. It’s very difficult to begin to help as this is posted.

Comment: Virtualbox version 6.1.40-154048~Ubuntu~jammy is not in the Ubuntu repositories, which suggests that your source is someplace else. The large number of errors suggest that version of Virtualbox is incompatible with your release of Ubuntu. Select a version that is compatible with whatever release of Ubuntu you are running.